# Single Stream TCP socket will use for inbound and outbound connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

Is it possible to use one Stream Socket for accept inbound connection and also for initiate outbound connection. The concept is for i want to use simultaneous-open socket for NAT traversal over TCP.

Comment: How would you make this work on a network level, where would the outgoing socket have to go to?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean by one stream socket, do you mean some stream sockets on one address? if this is true in TCP you can use `setsockopt` to set `SO_REUSEADDR` to `1` and then multiple sockets can share same address

Comment: For example: An application at host A uses 7777 as the local port and connects to port 8888 on host B. At the same time, an application at host B uses 8888 as the local port and connects to port 7777 on host A.

Comment: For your information i want to open single socket, which will do both connect and listen, is it possible?

Comment: TCP sockets are duplex, so when client on host A from 7777, connect to server on host B at 8888, it can both send and receive data, but you can have 2 connections with same source and destination address, either source or destination address must be different